# Execution order of eval-after-load vs hooks for a given major mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, initialization, hook, elisp, major-mode

Let's assume the particular mode I'm working with is `python-mode`.
The Emacs manual specifies following for hooks:

> Every major mode command is supposed to run a normal hook called the mode hook as one of the last steps of initialization.

From Major mode conventions:

> Each major mode should have a normal mode hook named `modename-mode-hook`. The very last thing the major mode command should do is to call `run-mode-hooks`.

And `with-eval-after-load` executes code after code is loaded (e.g. required), and runs immediately if already required.

I have following in my init file:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-post-python)
```

Also I have added

```
    (with-eval-after-load 'python-mode
     (setq-default python-basic-offset 7) ; setting some option
     (add-to-list 'python-globals-list "console"))
```

Now assuming I open Emacs, followed by opening a Python file buffer, what are the loading/execution orders with respect to hooks and `with-eval-after-load`? From the docs specified at start, it seems mode hooks will run before `with-eval-after-load` code?

More specifically, are mode hooks are run every time a buffer is entered/ made the current buffer? (P.S. this is hard to find from the docs/manual, any links clarifying any of the above in the docs/manual are welcome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now assuming I open emacs, followed by opening a python file buffer, what are the loading/execution order with respect to hooks and with-eval-after-load?

Assuming `python.el` has not *already* been loaded, then:

- You visit `foo.py`.
- `set-auto-mode` is called and determines that `python-mode` is appropriate, and calls that.
- The `python-mode` function is (at this point) an autoload definition for the `python-mode` library<sup>1</sup>, which is consequently loaded.
- At the end of loading, your `with-eval-after-load` for the `python-mode` library is evaluated.
- The real `python-mode` function (newly defined by loading the library) is called, at the end of which:
- `python-mode-hook` runs.

> Are mode hooks are run every time a buffer is entered/ made the current buffer?

No, they run every time the mode function is called.

---

<sup>1</sup> The default library is `python.el` which uses `(provide 'python)`, but from your `with-eval-after-load` you're evidentially using the `python-mode.el` library instead.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at source, and What I learned from this is that mode authors don't run hooks themselves (they just define the hooks with type hook), but in that case who does run the hook?

Comment: Major modes are usually defined with `define-derived-mode`, which automatically creates the hook variable and defines the mode command with a call to `run-mode-hooks`.

Comment: If, OTOH, you are *not* using a standard macro to define a mode function, then it is your responsibility to implement all such expected housekeeping manually.